# BCP database with period in name

Tags: .net, sql-server, bcp

I'm having trouble using the SQL BCP process to load up my tables with data. I'm calling it from a .NET application, so I execute the xp_cmdshell executable to run the bcp command. Here is what one of these commands looks like:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "[D001Test.Restore].[dbo].[GeneralComments]" in "<DataFile>" -q -c -t "|_|" -r "|+~+|" -k -V80 -a33000 -E -STest'
```

When the database name I am importing into (in this case D001Test.Restore) has a "." in the name, the bcp command fails. Is there any way around this? I have tried both with and without the brackets. I may have to import the data into a new database, and rename it to the desired name after it is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the -q argument and the quotation marks. The documentation states the following about the q argument:

> Use this option to specify a database,
>   owner, table, or view name that
>   contains a space or a single quotation
>   mark. Enclose the entire three-part
>   table or view name in quotation marks
>   ("").

Your database name contains neither space nor single quotation mark.

Try this:

```
bcp [D001Test.Restore].dbo.GeneralComments in "<DataFile>" -c -t "|_|" -r "|+~+|"
-k -V80 -a33000 -E -STest
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I will be testing it out. However, I still have the issue where the database name has a space and a period in the name. I've tentatively implemented a solution to use a temporary table with underscores replacing the periods, but its quite an ugly concept.

Comment: @Kevin If you have space and period in the database name then you need the quotation marks.
bcp "[D001 Test.Restore].dbo.GeneralComments" in "<DataFile>" -c -t "|_|" -r "|+~+|" -k -V80 -a33000 -E -STest

Comment: @Bill Unfortunately this doesn't work. If you use the quotes, the bcp process must be programmed to look for the periods, regardless of the brackets. So this: EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "[D019Restore.Generic Test].dbo.GeneralComments" out "<datafile" -q -c -t "|_|" -r "|+~+|" -k -V80 -a33000 -E        does not work. If I can't find a solution to this I'm pretty sure I'm going to have to do some hacky database renaming to get this to work. Also not the issue applies to both "in" and "out" bcp processes.

Comment: @Kevin Please note that I did not include -q argument in the argument list. Remove -q from your command and try again. Without -q it works for me.

Comment: strange. I tried it without the -q argument and no quotes and just received an error message in the output file. I'll try it again. I forgot to mention, and this may be the kicker, this has to be successful on Sql 2000, 2005, and 2008.

Comment: @Kevin Remove only the -q argument, but do not touch the quotation marks. I tried

bcp "[D001 Test.Restore].dbo.GeneralComments" in "<DataFile>" -c -t "|_|" -r "|+~+|" -k -V80 -a33000 -E -STest

on SQL Server 2005 and it works.

Comment: @Bill I appreciate your help on this. It looks as though you are correct, this does work on '05 and '08, but unfortunately it must be different in SQL 2000. I have tried pretty much every combination, and it still reads the period as the context delimiter, even inside the brackets. I get: "Cannot open database requested in login 'D001 Test'. Login Fails". This is with brackets and quotations, and no -q. Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: @Kevin Have you tried to use bcp.exe installed with SQL Server 2005 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe, File version: 2005.90.4035.0) to export/import data from/into SQL Server 2000? Try -V80 argument. I can not try it, because I have only SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Comment: @Bill, unfortunately, this process is running on customer's servers, so I really don't have the power to install a newer version of bcp on their system. The primary use of this feature is to allow them to backup a SQL 2008 db, and restore it on SQL 2000 (or 2005).